# Can I include an element from an xml file with php?

Tags: php, xml, post, dynamic

I have a list, consisting of links looking like this:

```
<a href=index.php?p=page_1>Page 1</a>
<a href=index.php?p=page_2>Page 2</a>
<a href=index.php?p=page_3>Page 3</a>
```

When clicked they include a page (page_1.inc.php or page_2.inc.php or page_3.inc.php) on my page thanks to this script:

```
<?php
  $pages_dir = 'pages';

  if(!empty($_GET['p'])){
      $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
      unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);

      $p = $_GET['p'];

      if (in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)){
          include ($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');
      }
      else {
          echo 'Sorry, could not find the page!';
      }
  }
  else {
      include($pages_dir.'/home.inc.php');
  }
?>
```

Period.

I also have an xml file looking like this:

```
<program>
    <item>
        <date>27/8</date>
        <title>Page 1</title>
        <info>This is info text</info>
    </item>
    <item>
        <date>3/9</date>
        <title>Page 2</title>
        <info>This is info text again</info>
    </item>
    <item>
        <date>10/9</date>
        <title>Page 3</title>
        <info>This just some info</info>
    </item>
</program>
```

This is what I want to achieve:
If I click on the link "Page 1" it will display "This is info text" on the page.
If I click on the link "Page 2" it will display "This is info text again" on the page.
If I click on the link "Page 3" it will display "This just some info" on the page.

Was I clear enough?
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/simplexmlelement) using the [xpath()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method.

```
$xmlString = file_get_contents("path/to/xml/file.xml");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
$info = $xml->xpath("/program/item[title='Page " . $page . "']/info");
echo (string) $info[0];
```

**Update:**

To get an array of all dates you would do something like this:

```
$xmlString = file_get_contents("path/to/xml/file.xml");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
$results = $xml->xpath("/program/item/date");

$dates = array();
if (!empty($results)) {
    foreach ($results as $date) {
        array_push($dates, (string) $date); // It's important to typecast from SimpleXMLElement to string here
    }
}
```

Also, you could combine the logic, if needed, from the first and second examples. You can reuse the `$xml` object for multiple XPath queries.

If you need `$dates` to be unique, you can either add an `in_array()` check before doing the `array_push()` or you can use `array_unique()` after the foreach.

Comment: Ok... Since I'm new to php and want to learn it, not just use it, let's see if I understand!
The two first rows reads the content of the xml file with the SimpleXMLElement function, right?
The third row sets $info to read the element "info" as a string for the "item" with the "title" that says $page.
The last row prints $info.
Am I right?

Comment: @Lindhe94 No worries. I was new to php once. Yes, the first two lines you are correct. The third line is using XPath (I suggest you read up on it) to scan the XML contained inside the `$xml` variable. That xpath query is filtering down to the XML node we care about. It's starting at `program` then going to all `item`'s and then limiting `item`'s returned which have a node `title` with the text "Page 1", "Page 2", etc. Finally, it selects the `info` node in that context. The text within the `info` node is returned as an array into `$info` which we just select the first index (only one result).